# What are good study guides/practice tests for the airframe maintenance certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, aircraft-maintenance, airframe

I am approaching my 18 month mark on the job. Wanting to get my A license first. I have done all kinds of airframe work in this time period. Wondering if anyone has suggestions for the names of the good practice tests books for general and airframe. I have the FAA books on all 3 subjects just no study guides or practice tests. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I used the [Dale Crane series](http://www.mypilotstore.com/MyPilotStore/sep/9872?gclid=CjwKEAjw0KK4BRDCiKHD5Ny8pHESJACLE620llqMaGXAXe6hSzL3NAOlQuGsJlPoB2fcQIzbqH1BvhoC_hrw_wcB) of study guides from [ASA](http://www.asa2fly.com/AMT-Test-Guide-Books-C39.aspx) years ago, available from either of those two links as well as many other places.

Here is the specific study guide for [Airframe](http://www.asa2fly.com/Fast-Track-2016-Test-Guide-Airframe-P2257.aspx), but you will also want the [General](http://www.asa2fly.com/Fast-Track-2016-Test-Guide-General-P2255C39.aspx) study guide. These are for written test prep, but *might* also include Oral and Practical (O&P) test prep.

[image: Dale Crane Test Guide Covers]

<sup>*Image from [mypilotstore.com](http://images.mypilotstore.com/products/9872.jpg) product listing*</sup>

There are also other options out there. Gleim offers an [AMT test prep course](https://www.gleim.com/aviation/amt/#avTab%3Dmain), as does ASA in their [AMT Prepware](http://www.mypilotstore.com/MyPilotStore/sep/10062), but I don't know that I have any experience with either one. I definitely used one of the digital test prep packages out there, but I can't remember which one. I do like the digital tests, especially since that is probably how you will be taking the writtens anyway.

I also studied the [Jeppesen](http://www.mypilotstore.com/MyPilotStore/secp/132) textbooks in addition to the FAA textbooks you mentioned.

You will also want to study the [Practical Test Standards (PTS)](http://www.mypilotstore.com/mypilotstore/sep/2147) for your O&P test prep.